# Scheduling Repeating Local Push Notification for Birthday Android

Tags: android, push-notification, calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //set notification for date --> 8th January 2010 at 9:06:00 PM
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 06);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

        // Enable {@code SampleBootReceiver} to automatically restart the alarm when the
        // device is rebooted.
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Here is my Main Activity code, i want it to trigger a push notification on 8th January every year or may be on the user's birthday, but its triggering this push notification daily and that's because i have mentioned "AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY". But how to make it work on a yearly basis, like it should only trigger the push notification on the user's birthday.

Thank You

Comment: Did you get how to do it?

Comment: No, I haven't got any solution to it till now..